# Can I install a sink sprayer with a bathroom faucet?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, bathroom-fixtures

I purchased a vessel type sink faucet made for bathrooms and installed it in my kitchen. How can I add a sink sprayer? If it has to be all cold water thats ok, but I think its possible to have a mixer added? Also I know it needs to have something on it so that there is not always water pressure on it or it will leak. I don't want to get a regular kitchen faucet as this one is quite unique (It's a dragon!!! ) but would love to add a working sprayer if possible. Thanks!

Comment: it's probably possible buit the details will depoend on what you have.

Comment: Yes, I've done that before using a compression-type connector to the supply line that does not have the metal jacket. You shall be able to find it from the plumbing parts supplier.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to this is likely a second faucet - one of the "modern" faucet-is-the-sprayer that pulls out types would be least intrusive.

Might look a little weird, but to get a mixer and a sprayer (without risking major surgery on your dragon faucet) you're pretty much looking at that or installing a shower valve for the mixer, and that's going to look more weird, I expect.